# Perl PPM Manager

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am running Windows 7 x64 bit OS and I am having trouble installing any packages through PPM Manager. For example, it's saying:

```
MIME-Base64 marked for install
Installing package ... 
  Downloading MIME-Base64-3.13 ... not found
Installing package failed

ERROR: 404 Not Found
```

This happens when I try to install any package. What could it be?

Comment: Do you have additional ppm repositories installed?

Comment: No, I don't think so? I will check on google for additional.

Comment: Yes, I have: http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm, for the www.bribes.org Perl 5.6, 5.8 and 5.10 repository
http://trouchelle.com/ppm, for the trouchelle.com Perl 5.8 repository
http://ppm.tcool.org/archives/, for the ppm.tcool Perl 5.8 repository
http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/cgi-bin/ppmserver?urn:/PPMServer, for the uwinnipeg Perl 5.6 repository
http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/cgi-bin/ppmserver?urn:/PPMServer58 (ActivePerl Builds < 819) / http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/ (ActivePerl Builds >= 819), for the uwinnipeg Perl 5.8 repository
http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/PPMPackages/10xx/, same issue.

Comment: :( I can't find anything on google for this. How strange, I am going to just reinstall active perl since I am running out of ideas.

Comment: I think I got it, I downloaded the latest active perl with modules pre compiled and it was a work around the problem.

Comment: I resolved the issue by installing the latest version of active perl and then following the proxy settings from http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#http_proxy all you do is add a new environment variable named http_proxy and give it this value:   http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy.example.org:8080.

Comment: @Christoper drop that in an answer and you can select it after a couple days.